# Matlab R2022b installer not working in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, matlab

I am trying to install Matlab R2022b along with Simulink (issue is happening with every version so it's probably something with my computer) on my Ubuntu 22.04. When I first tried installing it through the command line, the GUI opened, but for some reason, it stopped saying I didn't have enough disk space which I have plenty plentyyyyyy of! After that, I tried rerunning the installer, now the GUI doesn't even load, and the command does nothing. I was trying to install as guided [here](https://www.how2shout.com/linux/how-to-install-matlab-in-ubuntu-20-04/).

Comment: That guide is for 20.04 do you know this app runs on 22.04?

Comment: @David I just checked another guideline for 22.04, the instructions are the same.